# sql plus stops responding after calling a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, dbms-output

```
create or replace procedure pizza_qty(order_num IN order_list.order_no%type)  is
    cursor c1 is 
       select order_no,qty from order_list; 
    temp1 order_list.order_no%type;
    pizzacount order_list.qty%type;
    temp2 order_list.qty%type;
begin
    open c1;
    loop
        fetch c1 into temp1,temp2;
        if order_num=temp1 then
            pizzacount := pizzacount+1;
            --exit;
        elsif c1%notfound and pizzacount=0 then
            dbms_output.put_line('the order '||order_num||' is invalid..');
            exit;
        end if;
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line('the order '||order_num||' has '||pizzacount||' pizza(s) to be delivered');
    close c1;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

Code you wrote is ... well, rather strange. It presumes that ALL orders in that table should contain nothing but pizzas. Though, that's not the reason for your problems.

Declaring a variable, `pizzacount`, sets it to `null`. Anything `+ null` is still `null` so it is never set to anything else, so your loop never exits.

Moreover, you don't need cursor; a simple `select` is enough. If it returns something for that order number, then those must be pizzas. Otherwise, it won't return anything at all so order  number is invalid.

Something like this: test case first:

```
SQL> create table order_list (order_no number, qty number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into order_list (order_no, qty) values (1, 5);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure pizza_qty (par_order_num in order_list.order_no%type)
  2  is
  3    l_qty order_list.qty%type;
  4  begin
  5    select qty
  6      into l_qty
  7      from order_list
  8      where order_no = par_order_num;
  9
 10    dbms_output.put_line('Order ' || par_order_num || ' has ' || l_qty ||
 11                         ' pizza(s) to be delivered');
 12  exception
 13    when no_data_found then
 14      dbms_output.put_line('Order ' || par_order_num || ' is invalid');
 15  end;
 16  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> exec pizza_qty(1);
Order 1 has 5 pizza(s) to be delivered

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec pizza_qty(2);
Order 2 is invalid

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time it really helps